My images uploaded from ckeditor5 in django to cloudflare r2 stop working
So the images initially upload and are appear in my posts but eventually the link stops working after an hour or so. Has anyone had this issue before? It looks like they are going into the rootfolder in my mediabucket. Is anyone else using R2, Django, and CKeditor5
I've been messing with custom media storage but can't really find an example of what I'm trying to do

Did you find a solution to this?
